# SharePoint Site Malfunction

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, onedrive-for-business

Today when I opened up my SharePoint Site Collection, I found that alot of things are missing in the page, and the document library is not functioning

[image: Functions are missing in the red bar]

Normally the page should have functions such as project summary timeline, Newsfeed, Document display and options, also, on the top of the page, the setting options and links to OneDrive, Newsfeed, and Sites are missing as well.

[image]

How should I deal with this.
BTW  the central admin looks fine, but when i click on the Newsfeed, Onedrive or Sites, the page is just empty

[image]

If I click into Onedrive
[image]

What should I do here

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things that are missing are web services delivered.

Guesses:

- If this is happening in a single browser, something in stopping your JavaScript from running. Try another browser or PC.
- If this is happening in all browsers, then some JavaScript may have been added to your master page that is failing (generating errors). Use your browser's F12 tools to check for JavaScript errors. (Press F12, then reload the page and check for reported errors.)
- This could be an issue with your SharePoint servers, possibly IIS. So try restarting the web front end servers, or restarting IIS on those servers.

The most important question is "what has changed recently?"  Service packs on the server? Customizations to master pages?

Comment: I might have delete something in the design manager, would that be the problem? If it is the problem, is there anyway I can fix it or should I just delete the team site and recreate one, since its a test environment. Also, there are a lot of errors in the JavaScript, what is something that I should look for?